# Combine listbox numbers in correspondence to another listbox (VB.net)

Tags: vb.net, excel

It's hard to explain in words, but I'll try.
I am trying to read an excel sheet and put it into a listbox. One row is names, the other row is a number which belong to the name.

Example:

- James|100
- Chris|20
- Alex|50
- James|30
- Kate|60
- Chris|80

Left side is listbox1, right side is listbox2.
I want to combine the numbers in correspondence to each other & sort, so it would end like this:

- James|130
- Chris|100
- Kate|60
- Alex|50

I have tried, but can't seem to code a solution. Does anybody know what to do?

Here's my code so far:

```
For intLoopCounter = 1 To CInt(objXLWs.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Row)
            Try
                objRange = objXLWs.Range("I" & intLoopCounter)
                ListBox1.Items.Add(objRange.Value)
                objRange = objXLWs.Range("F" & intLoopCounter)
                ListBox2.Items.Add(objRange.Value)
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        Next intLoopCounter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe read the names in from excel to a Dictionary object? Then if the name already exists you can just add the previous value to the new value and you have your total value. Then you can iterate through all keys and place the value of the Key in the listbox.

```
Dim nameValDict as new Dictionary(of Object, Object)
Dim count as Integer = CInt(objXLWs.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Row)
For i = 1 to count
    Dim name = objRange = objXLWs.Range("I" & count )
    Dim val = objXLWs.Range("F" & count )
    if nameValDict.containsKey(name) then
        nameValDict.item(name) += val
    Else
        nameValDict.add(name, val)
    end If
Next

For each item in nameValDict.keys
    ListBox.Items.add(String.format("{0}|{1}", item, nameValDict.item(item)))
Next
```

P.S. this code probably won't work if you have `option strict on` and I haven't actually tested it because I don't have excel on my home machine. I just used your excel bits.